# Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'fileutils (= 1.0.2)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed a branch to Heroky and now I want to run the migrations or load the schema, either way I get:

```
Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'fileutils (= 1.0.2)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
```

I have tried restarting heroku (`heroku restart`) and then running `heroku run rake db:schema:load` but nothing happens.

I also tried running `gem update --default` but nothing changed.

I'm running Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.5.3, Heroku Cedar-14 Stack (it is deprecated, could this be causing the problem?)

Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    20: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
    19: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `activate_bin_path'
    18: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `synchronize'
    17: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:306:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    16: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:243:in `finish_resolve'
    15: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:397:in `resolve_current'
    14: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:385:in `resolve'
    13: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:188:in `resolve'
    12: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:42:in `resolve'
    11: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:64:in `resolve'
    10: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:106:in `start_resolution'
     9: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:165:in `initial_state'
     8: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:51:in `sort_dependencies'
     7: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:69:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
     6: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in `block in sort_dependencies'
     5: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `sort_dependencies'
     4: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `with_index'
     3: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `sort_by'
     2: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `each'
     1: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:283:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:231:in `search_for': Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'fileutils (= 1.0.2)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
```

Comment: Are you able to `bundle install` locally?

Comment: Also, can you please post full error. It seems like 2 gems require different versions of `fileutils`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale yes I can bundle install locally but nothing changes. I have added more info on the error I get printed from heroku

Answer (score 4):

I had this error after upgrade of bunlder to v1.9.9, and solved it with:

`sudo gem install bundler -v 1.17.3`

If you have several bundler versions installed, then you can run specific version of bundle this way: `bundle _1.17.3_ exec rspec`

Though seems like later bundler versions are pretty buggy, having one old bundler may work the best, at least this is what I have on my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

if running on a deprecated stack, upgrading it should solve the problem